# constraint formulation of optimization problem.

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, constraints

I have a optimization problem as follows:

minimize $ \sum_i \sum_j x_i x_j S_{ij} $

subject to the constraint

$x_i > a$  or $x_i=0$ for all indices and $ \sum_i x_i=1.0$

Can someone please help me to formulate this constraint. 
 How do it formulate this "or" condition that if $x_i$ not greater than "a" then it can be zero.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There's a couple of things wrong with this formulation. First, is there one constraint x_i > a? (for which i?), should there be a summation, or many constraints (with a_i on the right hand side)? Second, optimization does not do well with strict inequalities. I suspect you meant $x_i \ge a$.

Comment: Please try to fix the formulation, as pointed out by @user1612986, and use built-in tex support to write formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typical way to deal with such questions involves additional variables and a boundedness assumption. If you have an upper bound, say $M$, on $x_i$ that is automatically satisfied, then you can rewrite the two constraints as

$$M\ge x_i \ge a,$$
$$\mbox{or}$$
$$0\ge x_i \ge 0.$$

Now introduce a binary variable $z$ (which can only take two values, 0 and 1) and replace the constraints by
$$Mz \ge x_i,$$
$$x_i \ge az, $$
$$z = 0 \mbox{ or } z = 1.$$

Explanation: If $z = 0$, the two constraints collapse into $0\ge x_i\ge 0$ (or $x_i = 0$), and if $z=1$, then $M \ge x_i \ge a$ (or just $x_i\ge a$, since the left inequality is assumed to be automatically satisfied).